# Vector and Operator Combination Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to find an algorithm that will use any combination of a given set of operators on a given set of vectors to reach a target vector. At all costs I want to avoid using brute force, I believe this problem has an elegant solution.

**Example problem:**
Given the vectors `V1 = [0, -1]`; `V2 = [2, 1]`; `V3 = [-1, 0]`;
And the operators `L1` and `L2`. Who behave like `L1[V1, V2] = V1 + V2`; `L2[V1, V2] = V1/V2`
Try to reach the target vector `T = [-0.5, 0]`

**Solution:**
`L1[V1, V2] = [0, -1] + [2, 1] = [2, 0]`
`L2[V3, L1[V1, V2]] = [-1, 0] / [2, 0] = [-0.5, 0]` (0/0 division was pointed out to me, which was a mistake; but I think what the solution is trying to accomplish still makes sense)

**What I've Tried:**
I have tried treating this question as a `vector combination problem`, but I haven't figured out how to introduce a list of operators. Please let me know if my terminology is incorrect or confusing; any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's `V1/V2`? Is it an element wise division? It seems like these explain some sort of linear process. If I were to hazard a guess, you would create some matrix `S = A * B` where `S` is the solution constraints, `B` is the input, `A` is the resultant operation.

Comment: Yes, `V1/V2` is meant to be element division. Would the solution constraint be my target vector?

Comment: Yes it would. Not sure how to set it up but I'm thinking somewhere along the lines of discrete control for linear systems.

Comment: You got a 0/0=0 in your solution. Your division doesn't make sense...

Comment: Why would there be an elegant solution when the operators are completely arbitrary?

Comment: This set of problems includes NP hard problems, so you're not going to find a simple way of solving them in general.

Comment: For the sum operator, L1, in my example, you can solve it using multi variable system techniques. I consider that elegant. I'm fairly confident this can be expanded to all linear operators, but am uncertain about the non-linear ones. (I know this now, I didn't when I first posted this... still researching when I have free time)

Answer (score 1):

How about two-step algorithm?

1. With given set of vectors `V1, V2, V3 ...` try to solve linear equation: `a1 * V1 + a2 * V2 + ... = T` where coefficients are integers (Diophantine equation). Moreover all vectors can be scaled up to integers. This step corresponds to operation `L1`.
2. Expand the set of vectors with operation `L2` and go to step 1.

Comment: This is pretty close to brute force, feeding each generation of new vectors into L2 will be inefficient

Comment: This feeding is O(n^2) and in any kind of graph traverse you have this complexity. But there could be some heuristics which measures how far you are from right solution. Tell us if you find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not algorithmically elegant, but might help to speed up implementations, once somebody posts a good algorithmic answer:

Since each vector (say, of size `n`) is always processed as a whole, you could reduce the number of vector operations by a factor `n/s`. To do this, only execute (whatever algorithm you end up using) only on a sub-vector of each original vector (say, the first `s` elements).

In case your computer architecture is not capable of processing the vector as a whole, this will save at least the computational work to process all the components of the vectors.

Since you ignore some variables, this might produce false positives. So you need to verify your found solution. The probability of false positives can be adjusted by the size of `s` and which subset you use.

Applied to your example:

```
V1 = [0, -1]; V2 = [2, 1]; V3 = [-1, 0];
L1[V1, V2] = V1 + V2;
L2[V1, V2] = V1/V2
```

Only use `s=1`

```
V1' = [0]; V2' = [2]; V3 = [-1];
L1'[V1',V2'] = V1' + V2';
L2'[V1',V2'] = V1' / V2';

T = [-0.5]
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have m vectors and n operators, and assume that every operator takes two vectors as operands and produces one vector as output.

I've come up with a greedy algorithm that runs in O(mn + mlog(m)) time but it's **not** guaranteed to find the optimal solution. It goes as follows:

1. Sort the vector set according to their (squared) distance to the target vector. This runs in O(mlog(m)) time and only needs to be done once.
2. Select the two vectors from the vector set closest to the target and remove them from the vector set. This runs in O(1) time since you're removing 2 items from the end of an array (the sorted array of vectors).
3. Apply each of the operators to these two vectors and keep track of which operator results in the closest vector to the target vector. This runs in O(n) time. If the closest vector to the target vector matches it exactly, then break out of the algorithm.
4. Once the closest result is determined, insert that vector into the vector set at the appropriate location so the vector set remains sorted. This can be done in log(m) time.
5. Go back to 2.

Since, by the end of step 4, the number of vectors in the vector set has been reduced by 1 compared to its number at step 2, the process is bound to terminate.

What's the overall running time?

Steps 2 to 4 have a total running time of O(1) + O(n) + O(log(m)) = O(n + log(m)) and the number of times those steps have to be executed is O(m) so the total, including step 1, is

O(mn + mlog(m))

Of course, along the way you need to store sufficient information about the operators and their operands that result in the closest vector to the target so that you can build a tree that represents the operators and the order in which they need to be applied.

This algorithm's running time compares exceedingly favourably with the running time of a brute force algorithm that would try every combination of operators and operands, since that is clearly exponential on the size of the vector set.

Comment: This doesn't work for `V1=[0,1]`, `V2=[10,10]`, `V3=[-10,-10]`, `T=[0,0]`. The closest operands and intermediate results are not necessarily the most useful ones.

Comment: The method is not guaranteed to find the best solution. It's a greedy algorithm that will find a combination of operators and operands that results in a vector close to the target, as close as it **can** get through a greedy approach. It's not guaranteed to get the optimal solution.

Comment: It's not guaranteed to find *any* solution. You might as well just stop after step 4, and you'd have an even faster non-working algorithm.

Comment: I beg to differ. The question is to find **any combination** of the operators and it's not specified what is meant by _reaching_ the target. If the goal is to match the target exactly then there may not exist a solution yet my algorithm will find _some_ vector at the end that is close to the target, in some meaningful sense. If the goal is to match the target but not necessarily exactly then, again, my algorithm will find some combination of the operations and operands that will result in a vector close to the target in some well-defined (and measurable) way.

Comment: Reaching in this case means that if it's possible to exactly match it, then get the exact match. I think your solution is interesting and would be best applied when an exact match cannot be found.